# Импорт отдельной функции из своего модуля во Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

В приложении есть 2 файла: main.py и module.py

В module.py находится функция `get_project_list()`

```
def get_project_list():

    session = Session(bind=engine)
    project_query = session.query(Project).all()


    print(project_query)

    project_list = []
    for proj in project_query:
        project_list.append({'id': proj.id, 'name': proj.name, 'domain': proj.domain})

    session.close()
    return project_list
```

Сама по себе, если запустить файл модуля отдельно она работает, делает запрос в базу и возвращает результаты. Но если импортировать ее из файла main - возвращается пустой список.

```
@app.route('/project_list') 
def project_list():
    from module import get_project_list
    projects = get_project_list()
    return render_template('project.html', projects = projects)
```

Как правильно импортировать функцию в данном случае и в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Выглядит все правильно, возможно в module вне этой функции выполняется какой-то код, типо подключения к базе или что-то в таком роде. Когда вы вызвали в `main.py` функцию `projects = get_project_list()`, что напечатало в консоль `print(project_query)`? Кст, подправьте код в вопросе -- отступы разъехались, кнопка `править`

Comment: Печатается пустой массив, просто []. 

На самом деле условия задачи в реальности немного другие, т.к. модуль лежит в папке внутри приложения. Пути указаны верно, но  я прочитал, что в папке с модулями нужно обязательно создвать файл __init__.py. Создал - не помогло. 

И по поводу того, что Вы сказали - функция действительно подключается к базе. Класс Project - это таблица в БД, только разве это на что-то влияет? Ведь через if __name__ == 'main' все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, я понял причину. В файле model подключение к базе было прописано по относительному пути. Поэтому при импорте путь начинался от файла, в который импортирована функция. В общем, просто ошибка по глупости :)